# Values are not getting set in dropdownlist from JSON data using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a `json` data which I bind on `dropdownlist` using jquery for viewing purpose. But it is not setting the values for me. Below is what I tried

```js
function BindClickedData(jsonValue) {            

            try {
                var RRSOCDATA = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
                var getJSONValue = RRSOCDATA[0];
                
                if (getJSONValue.STATE != "" || getJSONValue.STATE != null) {
                    $('#ddlStateView').val(getJSONValue.STATE);
                }

               if (getJSONValue.CITY != "" || getJSONValue.CITY == null) {
                $('#txtCityView').val(getJSONValue.CITY);
            }
                catch (e) {
                alert('Some issues');
            }
   }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<select id="ddlStateView" runat="server"></select>
<input type="text" id="txtCityView" />
```

`textbox` values are getting set properly but not the `dropdownlist`. I don't know what might be the reason. Please suggest and also let me know if any doubts

Below is my JSON data

```js
{RRSOC_ID: 27934, STORE_CODE: "AC-12345", STATE: "Mumbai", CITY: "Mumbai", 
SITE_STORE_FORMAT: "My Jio Store",
ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID
:
"Sanjay.Mishra@ril.com"
ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER
:
"50007837"
ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO
:
"9766002405"
ALPM_ALPO_NAME
:
"Sanjay kumar  Mishra"
AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO
:
null
AREA_MANAGER_NAME
:
null
CAMERA_MODEL
:
null
CITY
:
"Mumbai"
CREATED_BY
:
"NADEEM5.KHAN"
CREATED_DATE
:
"2018-05-16T15:33:25"
CST_TIN_NO
:
null
DELETED_BY
:
null
DVR_IP_ADDRESS
:
null
DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY
:
null
EMP_NEAREST_STORE
:
null
EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO
:
null
FACILITY_TEAMNO
:
null
FACILTY_TEAMNAME
:
null
ISACTIVE
:
"Y"
IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL
:
"Yes"
IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL
:
"Yes"
IS_STORE_IN_MALL
:
"Yes"
LAST_UPDATED_BY
:
"NADEEM5.KHAN"
LAST_UPDATED_DATE
:
"2018-05-16T15:33:25"
LATITUDE
:
null
LAUNCH_DATE
:
null
LONGITUDE
:
null
LPA
:
null
LPO_MOBILENO
:
null
MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO
:
"9821283975"
MANAGER_MOBNO
:
null
NAME_ALIGNED_LPO
:
null
NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME
:
null
NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO
:
null
NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO
:
null
NEAREST_HOSP_NAME
:
null
NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO
:
null
NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME
:
null
NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME
:
"Nadeem Khan"
NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO
:
"8898585969"
NO_OF_CAMERA
:
null
NO_OF_POS
:
null
PATROL_PARTY_NAME
:
"Abusad shaikh"
PATROL_PARTY_NO
:
"7204852360"
RRSOC_ID
:
27934
SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE
:
null
SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE
:
null
SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS
:
null
SITE_STORE_FORMAT
:
"My Jio Store"
SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER
:
"50030992"
SLP_STATE_EMAILID
:
"Devendra.Ingle@ril.com"
SLP_STATE_HEAD
:
"Devendra Ingle"
SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO
:
"9168546754"
SLP_ZONAL_ECNUMBER
:
"50023405"
SLP_ZONAL_EMAILID
:
"Ajay.Dhawan@ril.com"
SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME
:
"Ajay Dhawan"
SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NO
:
"7021051806"
STATE
:
"Mumbai"
STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME
:
null
STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO
:
null
STORE_ADDRESS
:
null
STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO
:
null
STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME
:
null
STORE_CODE
:
"AC-12345"
STORE_EMAILID
:
null
STORE_MANAGER_NAME
:
null
STORE_SITENAME
:
null
STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1
:
null
STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2
:
null
STORE_SPACE_SQFT
:
null
SUPERVISOR_MOBNO
:
null
SUPERVISOR_NAME
:
null
```

**JSON**

```
[{"RRSOC_ID":27934.0,"STORE_CODE":"AC-12345","STATE":"Mumbai","CITY":"Mumbai","SITE_STORE_FORMAT":"My Jio Store","STORE_SITENAME":null,"STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_1":null,"STORE_SITENAME_LANDL_2":null,"STORE_ASST_MANAGER_NAME":null,"STORE_ASST_MANAGER_MOBNO":null,"STORE_MANAGER_NAME":null,"MANAGER_MOBNO":null,"EMP_NEAREST_STORE":null,"EMP_NEAREST_STORE_MOBNO":null,"SUPERVISOR_NAME":null,"SUPERVISOR_MOBNO":null,"SECURITY_SUP_NAME_STORE":null,"SECURITY_SUP_MOBNO_STORE":null,"NAME_ALIGNED_LPO":null,"LPO_MOBILENO":null,"ALPM_ALPO_NAME":"Sanjay kumar  Mishra","ALPM_ALPO_MOBNO":"9766002405","AREA_MANAGER_NAME":null,"AREA_MANAGER_MOBNO":null,"SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NAME":"Ajay Dhawan","SLP_ZONAL_HEAD_NO":"7021051806","DVR_IP_ADDRESS":null,"SIGNET_IP_ADDRESS":null,"NEAREST_POLICE_STN_NAME":null,"NEAREST_POLICE_STN_CONTNO":null,"NEAREST_HOSP_NAME":null,"NEAREST_HOSP_CONTNO":null,"NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNAME":null,"NEAREST_FIRE_STN_CONTNO":null,"STORE_SPACE_SQFT":null,"STORE_ADDRESS":null,"LAUNCH_DATE":null,"CST_TIN_NO":null,"STORE_EMAILID":null,"NO_OF_POS":null,"NO_OF_CAMERA":null,"DVR_MODEL_GESECURITY":null,"CAMERA_MODEL":null,"ALIGNED_LPO_MAILDID":"Sanjay.Mishra@ril.com","FACILTY_TEAMNAME":null,"FACILITY_TEAMNO":null,"STATE_HEAD_OPS_NAME":null,"STATE_HEAD_OPS_NO":null,"LPA":null,"SLP_STATE_HEAD":"Devendra Ingle","SLP_STATE_HEAD_NO":"9168546754","CREATED_BY":"NADEEM5.KHAN","CREATED_DATE":"2018-05-16T15:33:25","LAST_UPDATED_BY":"NADEEM5.KHAN","LAST_UPDATED_DATE":"2018-05-16T15:33:25","ISACTIVE":"Y","LATITUDE":null,"LONGITUDE":null,"DELETED_BY":null,"SLP_STATE_EMAILID":"Devendra.Ingle@ril.com","SLP_ZONAL_ECNUMBER":"50023405","SLP_ZONAL_EMAILID":"Ajay.Dhawan@ril.com","SLP_STATE_ECNUMBER":"50030992","ALPM_ALPO_ECNUMBER":"50007837","IS_STORE_IN_MALL":"Yes","MALL_CONTROL_ROOM_NO":"9821283975","IS_NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_AVAIL":"Yes","NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NAME":"Nadeem Khan","NIGHT_SEC_GUARD_NO":"8898585969","IS_NIGHT_PATROL_PARTY_AVAIL":"Yes","PATROL_PARTY_NAME":"Abusad shaikh","PATROL_PARTY_NO":"7204852360"}]
```

Comment: I think your javascript is missing a '}'. Look slightly above the catch block...

Comment: @Tyler: No updated that, but this is not the actual issue

Comment: Are you certain that `getJSONValue.STATE` is a valid value for your dropdownlist? Have you verified this using debugger tools?

Comment: @Tyler: Yes I have verifed that by checking in console.

Comment: @Tyler updated the question. do have a look

Comment: That's not valid JSON. JSON requires commas to end all statements except the final statement of a block/file.

Comment: @Tyler: if its not valid then how it is working for other values. ?? its not setting values only for dropdownlist

Comment: Okay, from what I see this should work. So, the only thing we haven't seen the is what the options are inside your dropdownlist. Can I trouble you to grab the option for "Mumbai"?

Comment: ok, so you want to see the option. ??

Comment: Yes, please. Everything that we've seen appears to be fine. So all that is left is the option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171201/discussion-between-bnn-and-tyler).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` of `try` block before the `catch`. use proper indentations it will help produce less bugs.

```js
function BindClickedData(jsonValue) {
  try {
    var RRSOCDATA = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
    var getJSONValue = RRSOCDATA[0];

    if (getJSONValue.STATE != "" || getJSONValue.STATE != null) {
        $('#ddlStateView').val(getJSONValue.STATE);
    }

    if (getJSONValue.CITY != "" || getJSONValue.CITY == null) {
        $('#txtCityView').val(getJSONValue.CITY);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    alert('Some issues');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<select id="ddlStateView" runat="server"></select>
<input type="text" id="txtCityView" />
```

Comment: No brother, that is not the issue. Updated that still not binding the values

Comment: @BNN I guess then you need to provide more info in the question detail. As with current info only found this problem.

Comment: Do share the JSON you are testing against.

Comment: @BNN You have shared the object only Do share the exact JSON string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:- You were missing the option element of select element and also you need to update returning JSON data, try the following code.

```
var ele = document.getElementById('ddlStateView');
    for (var i = 0; i < getJSONValue.STATE.length; i++) {
        // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
        ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML +
            '<option value="' + STATE[i]['ID'] + '">' + STATE[i]['STATE_NAME'] + '</option>';
    }
```